# Intuitive explanation of differential scattering cross-section

Tags: scattering-cross-section

I'm looking for a conceptual, intuitive understanding of the differential [cross section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_section_%28physics%29) (classical scattering). Its origin, its use, the general process for derivation (conceptually, rather than the mathematical minutiae). Can anyone provide one?

Comment: there is a good outline in  classical mechanics, kibble, http://amzn.to/1Vd9s24  maybe use the look inside the book feature (for free:), I recommend this because I think otherwise your question may be deemed too broad for here.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but the preview doesn't include it, and I don't have access to the book. I have looked through Lifshitz and Goldstein, but their stuff wasn't entirely satisfying. The question has been asked here before and not closed down, but there wasn't an answer - just the OP reporting that he/she had figured it out.

Comment: Your link already have a section about differential cross section. So what more do you want exactly ?